# Changing server.js file for exporting socket.io to the web using heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I am in the process of exporting a HTML5 project that uses socket.io and node.js, to the web, using heroku on the command line. The command `git push heroku master` works successfully, and the game works on localhost. However, when using `heroku open`, even in conjunction with `heroku ps:scale web=1`, the project javascript does not seem to connect to the server. Specifically, the html and css works, and the initial server message is displayed in the console, but the client never seems to send any information to the server with sockets.io.

I believe I need to change the initial lines of server.js, but am not sure exaclty how. Those lines are posted below:

```
    // Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app); 
var io = socketIO(server); 



     //App Setup
        enter code here`app.set('port',5000); 
        enter code here`app.use('/static',express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
        }); //USED TO BE THERE

        //Start the Server
        /*
        server.listen(5000,function() {
          console.log("Starting on localhost:50000");
        });
        */
         let port = process.env.PORT;
          if (port == null || port == "") {
            port = 8082;
          }

          server.listen(port, function () {
            console.log(`(1)Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
          });
```

The javascript for the client is found in static/Game.js in the same directory as server.js.
In addition, here is the github repository for the project: https://github.com/abinav-baskar/ColourGame

Apologies for the barebones question. If there is any more information I should provide, or research, troubleshooting I should do myself, I will do. Thank you,

Comment: Is it currently online, if so it would be awesome if you could send us the link

Comment: I'll try to keep the [link](https://thawing-plateau-81557.herokuapp.com) open for the next 24 hours or more

Comment: I found the issue, you named your game.js file `Game.js` on your repo, however, you are getting it on your application as `game.js` just change it to `Game.js` and it should work

Comment: @Ameer you were absolutely right! Changing the <script> tag in index.html to /Static/Game.js was indeed the change that allowed the html to use the javascript. Thank you for looking over the repo so thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting to update the question as 'solved'. The solution was specific to my case; as @Ameer explained in the comments on the question, there was a capitalisation issue in the script tag of my html.